# How to create makefile for Lazarus projects?

Tags: command-line, compilation, lazarus, fpc

After doing a light search on the [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org) site I've come to the conclusion that this question has been asked some times but I haven't found an answer, so I'll ask my SO peers.

Is there a a way to create a Makefile to replicate the action of the [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org) IDE when it compiles a project.

If so I really don't mind if it's makefile.fpc or just plain makefile, I just want some pointers on how to get to it.

BTW, I've tried the option to enable the Makefile on the Lazarus options. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik the key is "lazbuild", which is the cmdline build tool.

But no, afaik there is no makefile generation option, and I doubt there will ever be one.

FPC/lazarus use makefiles internally, to iterate over packages, but they don't generate a makefile for each compile like other systems do.

Comment: So does Lazarus just issue a VERY LONG command line with all the paths on it?

Comment: Afaik yes. It theory it could also write those to file first

Comment: And I suppose you're not on the Lazarus team right? :) So no use in me asking for that feature to you.

Comment: Hummm, looking at lazbuild on the wiki  and extrapolating on what it does internally, I could probably do some shell magic if I get time to grok lazbuild's source... Interesting. Or, use lazbuild in the chain. I'll have to give this thought some more time/investigation.

Answer (score 2):

```
lazbuild -B project.lpi
```

will rebuild the whole project.

```
lazbuild project.lpi
```

will compile the whole project, looking only at changed files.

see here for more references and detailed usage:
http://wiki.freepascal.org/lazbuild

```
lazbuild --create-makefile
```

might create a makefile, but i haven't tested this yet.